# Android application has stopped

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development and i got an issue that i haven't been able to fix. The application stops working and i get an "error inflating class". I'm simply trying to change the launcher xml file to another one.

This is my splash.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:background="@drawable/background">


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Splash.java file:

```
package com.carpool.jad;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}

}
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.carpool.jad"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat report:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carpool.jad/com.carpool.jad.Splash}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks :)

Comment: post your logcat error report..

Comment: Please post your logcat.

Comment: Inflating xml errors sounds like a build issue. Have you tried to clean the project? Is the `background` drawable available?

Comment: error will not come in this coding,clean and build and run

Comment: i've tried cleaning the project. the background drawable is available. it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you totally sure that you copied the correct splash.xml file content here? Have you multiple splash.xml files in your layout-*dpi folders

Comment: what is the size of the image you used for background?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this just copy and paste this in your xml ......replacing your previous code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/background">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do not modify your existing code .......remove that and put this ......then it will definately work.

Comment: oh ok. I will try to reinstall eclipse and maybe the sdk. thanks

Comment: reinstalling is not exact solution for any problem, you should find out perfect reason of this problem

Comment: yea you're right because reinstalling didn't fix it. Instead, i tried changing the jpg file and it worked! Although nothing pointed to the jpg being the problem